# Format-agnostic Zip Extraction Tool

Tags: command-line, compression

I like being in the command line a lot for efficiency, but one thing I always end up using the GUI for is extracting compressed folders, because the command line tools for unzipping the different types of archives (gzip vs. zip vs. tar vs...) have different arguments and I can never remember them all.

Is there a command line tool that has a simple interface for extracting a file archive of any type?

Comment: One solution may be to create your own bash script that will pass the compressed file(s) through the right command and options based on the input file extension.

Comment: You can tell `file-roller` to do quite a bit of stuff via the terminal - but it still pops up with a GUI.

Comment: @user68186 great idea, but the point of this post is that I was hoping someone had already done that work for me :)

Comment: Try installing the utility `p7zip` if not installed. The command `7z` can handle most compressed archives. I have not tried it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use a bash function which runs different commands based on the file type to extract it.

One good function that I'm aware is the one bellow. Put it in your `.bashrc` and then use it like `ex file`.

```bsh
# ex - archive extractor
# usage: ex <file>
ex ()
{
  if [ -f $1 ] ; then
    case $1 in
      *.tar.bz2)   tar xjf $1   ;;
      *.tar.gz)    tar xzf $1   ;;
      *.bz2)       bunzip2 $1   ;;
      *.rar)       unrar x $1   ;;
      *.gz)        gunzip $1    ;;
      *.tar)       tar xf $1    ;;
      *.tbz2)      tar xjf $1   ;;
      *.tgz)       tar xzf $1   ;;
      *.zip)       unzip $1     ;;
      *.Z)         uncompress $1;;
      *.7z)        7z x $1      ;;
      *)           echo "'$1' cannot be extracted via ex()" ;;
    esac
  else
    echo "'$1' is not a valid file"
  fi
}
```

You have to install these packages for this function to work correctly:

```
$ sudo apt install tar bzip2 gzip unrar gunzip unzip p7zip-full
```

---

I originally saw it couple of days ago on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_NRJU37DQLM) video, but found it by searching at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jlhg/9366374).